# AD filter: remove space in attribute

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

i got a vbs asp script and uses this filter.

```
strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=" & sFirstName & "*)(sn=" & sLastName & "*)(telephonenumber=*)"
```

the telephonenumber got spaces. how could I trim the spaces?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry for not answering this earlier.

the 1st script is as below

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%
' List script
'Option Explicit
%>
<%
response.ContentType="text/xml"
response.Expires = -1

Dim objCon, objCom, objRS
Dim strDNSDomain, strBase, strQuery, strFilter, strAttributes
Dim sFirstName: sFirstName = request.querystring("f")
Dim sLastName: sLastName = request.querystring("l")
Dim sSearchparam: sSearchparam = request.querystring("searchparam")
Dim strPage: strPage = request.querystring("page")

' Define the AD OU that contains our users and filter and attributes
strBase = "<LDAP://server.com/DC=server,DC=com>"
strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=" & sFirstName & "*)(sn=" & sLastName & "*)(telephonenumber=*))"
strAttributes = "givenName,sn,displayName,telephonenumber,mobile,c"

' Make AD connection and run query
Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
objCon.Properties("User ID") = "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
objCon.Properties("Password") = "PASSWORD"
objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon

strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
objCom.CommandText = strQuery
objCom.Properties("Sort On") = "displayName"

Set objRS = objCom.Execute
''''''''''
' Loop over returned recordset and output HTML

response.write ("<CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>")
response.write ("<Title>Phone Directory</Title><Prompt>Search Results</Prompt>")
'''''

If objRS.RecordCount <=30 then
 while not objRS.EOF
  response.write ("<DirectoryEntry>")
  response.write ("<Name>" & objRS("displayName") & " " & objRS("c") & "</Name>")
  response.write ("<Telephone>" & objRS("telephonenumber") & "</Telephone>")
  response.write ("</DirectoryEntry>")
  objRS.MoveNext
  Response.Flush
 wend

 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Dial</Name><URL>SoftKey:Dial</URL><Position>1</Position></SoftKeyItem>")
 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Exit</Name><URL>SoftKey:Exit</URL><Position>4</Position></SoftKeyItem>")

Else

 If strPage = "" then strPage = 1
 objRS.absoluteposition = 30 * strPage - 29
 For intRecord = 1 to 30
  response.write ("<DirectoryEntry>")
  response.write ("<Name>" & objRS("displayName") & " " & objRS("c") & "</Name>")
  response.write ("<Telephone>" & objRS("telephonenumber") & "</Telephone>")
  response.write ("</DirectoryEntry>")
  objRS.MoveNext
  Response.Flush
  If objRS.EOF then exit for
 next

 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Dial</Name><URL>SoftKey:Dial</URL><Position>1</Position></SoftKeyItem>")

 if 30 * strPage - 29 > 1 then 
  response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Prev</Name><URL>http://" & request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME") & ":" & request.servervariables("SERVER_PORT") & request.servervariables("url") & "?page=" & strPage - 1 & "&amp;f=" & sFirstName & "&amp;l=" & sLastName & "&amp;searchparam=" & server.urlencode(sSearchparam) & "</URL><Position>2</Position></SoftKeyItem>")
 end if

 if objRS.RecordCount > strPage * 30 then 
  response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Next</Name><URL>http://" & request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME") & ":" & request.servervariables("SERVER_PORT") & request.servervariables("url") & "?page=" & strPage + 1 & "&amp;f=" & sFirstName & "&amp;l=" & sLastName & "&amp;searchparam=" & server.urlencode(sSearchparam) & "</URL><Position>3</Position></SoftKeyItem>")
 end if

 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Exit</Name><URL>SoftKey:Exit</URL><Position>4</Position></SoftKeyItem>")

End If

'''''
response.write ("</CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>")

''''''''''
' Clean up
objRS.Close
objCon.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objCon = Nothing
Set objCom = Nothing
%>
```

the ciscophonedirectory would returned a number with spaces.

i added 2 variables

```
Dim strNumber
Dim strNumberClean
```

and updated the script as below

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%
' List script
'Option Explicit
%>
<%
response.ContentType="text/xml"
response.Expires = -1

Dim objCon, objCom, objRS
Dim strDNSDomain, strBase, strQuery, strFilter, strAttributes
Dim sFirstName: sFirstName = request.querystring("f")
Dim sLastName: sLastName = request.querystring("l")
Dim sSearchparam: sSearchparam = request.querystring("searchparam")
Dim strPage: strPage = request.querystring("page")
Dim strNumber
Dim strNumberClean

' Define the AD OU that contains our users and filter and attributes
strBase = "<LDAP://server.com/DC=server,DC=com>"
strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=" & sFirstName & "*)(sn=" & sLastName & "*)(telephonenumber=*))"
strAttributes = "givenName,sn,displayName,telephonenumber,mobile,c"

' Make AD connection and run query
Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
objCon.Properties("User ID") = "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
objCon.Properties("Password") = "PASSWORD"
objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon

strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
objCom.CommandText = strQuery
objCom.Properties("Sort On") = "displayName"

Set objRS = objCom.Execute
''''''''''
' Loop over returned recordset and output HTML

response.write ("<CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>")
response.write ("<Title>Phone Directory</Title><Prompt>Search Results</Prompt>")
'''''

If objRS.RecordCount <=30 then
 while not objRS.EOF
  response.write ("<DirectoryEntry>")
  response.write ("<Name>" & objRS("displayName") & " " & objRS("c") & "</Name>")

'Remove spaces in the Telephone Number - 20170127 Louis-Philippe Descamps 
  strNumber = objRS("telephonenumber")
  strNumberClean = Replace(strNumber," ","",1,-1)
  response.write ("<Telephone>" & strNumberClean & "</Telephone>")

  response.write ("</DirectoryEntry>")
  objRS.MoveNext
  Response.Flush
 wend

 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Dial</Name><URL>SoftKey:Dial</URL><Position>1</Position></SoftKeyItem>")
 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Exit</Name><URL>SoftKey:Exit</URL><Position>4</Position></SoftKeyItem>")

Else

 If strPage = "" then strPage = 1
 objRS.absoluteposition = 30 * strPage - 29
 For intRecord = 1 to 30
  response.write ("<DirectoryEntry>")
  response.write ("<Name>" & objRS("displayName") & " " & objRS("c") & "</Name>")

'Remove spaces in the Telephone Number - 20170127 Louis-Philippe Descamps 
  strNumber = objRS("telephonenumber")
  strNumberClean = Replace(strNumber," ","",1,-1)
  response.write ("<Telephone>" & strNumberClean & "</Telephone>")

  response.write ("</DirectoryEntry>")
  objRS.MoveNext
  Response.Flush
  If objRS.EOF then exit for
 next

 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Dial</Name><URL>SoftKey:Dial</URL><Position>1</Position></SoftKeyItem>")

 if 30 * strPage - 29 > 1 then 
  response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Prev</Name><URL>http://" & request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME") & ":" & request.servervariables("SERVER_PORT") & request.servervariables("url") & "?page=" & strPage - 1 & "&amp;f=" & sFirstName & "&amp;l=" & sLastName & "&amp;searchparam=" & server.urlencode(sSearchparam) & "</URL><Position>2</Position></SoftKeyItem>")
 end if

 if objRS.RecordCount > strPage * 30 then 
  response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Next</Name><URL>http://" & request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME") & ":" & request.servervariables("SERVER_PORT") & request.servervariables("url") & "?page=" & strPage + 1 & "&amp;f=" & sFirstName & "&amp;l=" & sLastName & "&amp;searchparam=" & server.urlencode(sSearchparam) & "</URL><Position>3</Position></SoftKeyItem>")
 end if

 response.write ("<SoftKeyItem><Name>Exit</Name><URL>SoftKey:Exit</URL><Position>4</Position></SoftKeyItem>")

End If

'''''
response.write ("</CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>")

''''''''''
' Clean up
objRS.Close
objCon.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objCon = Nothing
Set objCom = Nothing
%>
```

this seems to have done the trick.

the returned directory number doesnt have spaces anymore.

thanks

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Consider that it is the users who are at risk from poor password handling.

Comment: thanks for your comment. no idea how to do that but will have a look. cheers

Comment: @Ask yourself: "Is the security of the users worth researching how to handle passwords correctly?" Here is that happens: An attacker gains access to your site name/passwords, and you do not even know that. The the attacker used those to access the user's accounts on other systems because most users reuse passwords. Or he aggregates the stolen credentials with others and sells then on the dark web.

Comment: this is a internal service not exposed to the outside. the service runs on a ip phone phone. the account used in this script is a read only service account that can only read 1st name, 2nd name and phone extension.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information on this question, I'm assuming you want to strip the spaces from the telephone number results that you receive.

Alternatively, if you want further information on filter alteration, look here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

```
Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
base  = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
strFilter  = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=" & sFirstName & "*)(sn=" & sLastName & "*)(telephonenumber=*)"
attr  = "telephoneNumber"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";"

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  WScript.Echo Replace(rs.Fields("telephoneNumber").Value, " ", "")
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```